# Read var outside of global object

Tags: javascript, angular, scope

In my project I am using `kendo-ui`. Therefore in `ngOnInit` life-cycle Hook
I am trying to create something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  let hello = 600;
  public bulletData: any[] = [200, this.hello];
  public bulletValueAxis: any = {
     min: 0,
     max: this.hello
  };
}
```

It doesn't work !

*Global object and array don't see var which is outside. Do anyone know how I can solve this problem?*

Comment: just put hello remove this.hello

Comment: ERROR ReferenceError: hello is not defined

Answer (score 0):

`hello` variable is not defined as component's property, so it does not belong to `this.`
 
Also declare your component properties out of `ngOnInit`.
Try this:

[Working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tJJPQE?p=preview)

```
public bulletData: any[];
public bulletValueAxis: any;

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
     let hello = 600;
     this.bulletData = [200, hello];
     this.bulletValueAxis = {
       min: 0,
       max: hello
    };
}
```

Comment: I tryed it. First I declared hello inside ngOnInit or ngDoCheck and in next step i used your code. Console wrote me an error "ERROR ReferenceError: hello is not defined "

Comment: @komandir87 Check my updated answer, also including a working plunkr